# ImageView Drag Limitation In Android

Tags: java, android, touch-event, ontouchlistener

I have an ImageView in a layout and set OnTouchListener on ImageView to drag the ImageView. It's working perfectly. My problem is how can I prevent from move ImageView to out of layout range?

This is my code:

Activity class:

```
public class RepositionTestActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.reposition_test_layout);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.android);
        imageView.setOnTouchListener(new Touch());
    }
}
```

Touch class:

```
public class Touch implements OnTouchListener {

    private static final int NONE = 0;
    private static final int DRAG = 1;
    private static final int ZOOM = 2;

    private static final float MIN_ZOOM = 1f;
    private static final float MAX_ZOOM = 5f;

    private Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    private Matrix savedMatrix = new Matrix();

    private PointF start = new PointF();
    private PointF mid = new PointF();

    private int mode = NONE;
    private float oldDistance = 1f;

    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView)view;

        switch(event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
                mode = DRAG;
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                oldDistance = spacing(event);
                if(oldDistance > 10f) {
                    savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                    midPoint(mid, event);
                    mode = ZOOM;
                }
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                mode = NONE;
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                if(mode == DRAG) {
                    matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                    matrix.postTranslate(event.getX() - start.x, event.getY() - start.y);
                }
                else if(mode == ZOOM) {
                    float newDistance = spacing(event);
                    if(newDistance > 10f) {
                        matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                        float scale = newDistance / oldDistance;
                        float[] values = new float[9];
                        matrix.getValues(values);
                        float currentScale = values[Matrix.MSCALE_X];
                        if(scale * currentScale > MAX_ZOOM) 
                            scale = MAX_ZOOM / currentScale;
                        else if (scale * currentScale < MIN_ZOOM)
                            scale = MIN_ZOOM / currentScale;
                        matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
        imageView.setImageMatrix(matrix);
        return true;
    }

    private float spacing(MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
        float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
        return FloatMath.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
    }

    private void midPoint(PointF point, MotionEvent event) {
        point.set((event.getX(0) + event.getX(1)) / 2, (event.getY(0) + event.getY(1)) / 2);
    }

}
```

Layout xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/reposition_test_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/android"
        android:src="@drawable/android"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:scaleType="matrix"
        android:contentDescription="@string/android_description" >
    </ImageView>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: I edit it. You can see full class.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add the following parameters to the `Touch` class:

```
private float dx; // postTranslate X distance
private float dy; // postTranslate Y distance
private float[] matrixValues = new float[9];
float matrixX = 0; // X coordinate of matrix inside the ImageView
float matrixY = 0; // Y coordinate of matrix inside the ImageView
float width = 0; // width of drawable
float height = 0; // height of drawable
```

Modify your code after `case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:`

```
if (mode == DRAG) {
        matrix.set(savedMatrix);

        matrix.getValues(matrixValues);
        matrixX = matrixValues[2];
        matrixY = matrixValues[5];
        width = matrixValues[0] * (((ImageView) view).getDrawable()
                                .getIntrinsicWidth());
        height = matrixValues[4] * (((ImageView) view).getDrawable()
                                .getIntrinsicHeight());

        dx = event.getX() - start.x;
        dy = event.getY() - start.y;

        //if image will go outside left bound
        if (matrixX + dx < 0){
            dx = -matrixX;
        }
        //if image will go outside right bound
        if(matrixX + dx + width > view.getWidth()){
            dx = view.getWidth() - matrixX - width;
        }
        //if image will go oustside top bound
        if (matrixY + dy < 0){
            dy = -matrixY;
        }
        //if image will go outside bottom bound
        if(matrixY + dy + height > view.getHeight()){
            dy = view.getHeight() - matrixY - height;
        }
        matrix.postTranslate(dx, dy);   
    }
```

Comment: Thank you So much for this code.
Do you have same code for iphone?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your support. I also want to bound an image when i zoom an image. please also provide solution for it.

Comment: Hi @Anshul. It is better if you ask another question on SO so that others may see it and help you.

Comment: Hi, I need it i have done but sometimes it showing problem.

please help. I am posting my code please check.

Comment: Benito Bertoli... u just saved the entire alpha quadrant :)

Comment: All it cost was the life of one Apple senator, one criminal, and the self-respect of one Google Officer.

Comment: Would you please notice my question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34154187/how-to-avoid-zoomed-imageview-from-being-dragged-out-of-the-screen

Comment: @BenitoBertoli One question, how do I know if I'm dragging near to the end of the device? Means if I'm dragging an ImageView how to dectect that it's almost "gone" because no more space of the screen?

Comment: Can  you please  tell me use of matrix,start

Answer (score 1):

Android documentation says:

> It is possible to retrieve the location of a view by invoking the
>   methods **getLeft()** and **getTop()**. The former returns the left, or X,
>   coordinate of the rectangle representing the view. The latter returns
>   the top, or Y, coordinate of the rectangle representing the view.
>   These methods both return the location of the view relative to its
>   **parent**.
>   In addition, several convenience methods are offered to
>   avoid unnecessary computations, namely **getRight()** and **getBottom()**.
>   These methods return the coordinates of the right and bottom edges of
>   the rectangle representing the view. For instance, calling getRight()
>   is similar to the following computation: getLeft() + getWidth().

So you can get your image coordinates before moving it,and you can compute measure of movement in your **OnTouchListener** class.Now if (*`X coordinate of your image plus horizontal movement that you computed,be greater than device width`* or *`Y coordinate of your image plus vertical movement that you computed,be greater than device height`*) your image not move.

Comment: Although this information is right, translations ignore the left and top properties. So you can have a != 0 xy translation and still get getTop() and getLeft() as = 0.

Answer (score 1):

I used the answer from Benito Bertoli and modified the ACTION_MOVE code changing minor and major sign to make image zoom and drag for image zoomed

here´s the code

```
private static final float MIN_ZOOM = 1f; 
private static final float MAX_ZOOM = 2.5f; 

public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    ImageView view = (ImageView) v;
    view.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);

    // Handle touch events here...
    switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: //first finger down only
            savedMatrix.set(matrix);
            start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
            Log.d(TAG, "mode=DRAG" );
            mode = DRAG;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: //first finger lifted
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP: //second finger lifted
            mode = NONE;
            Log.d(TAG, "mode=NONE" );
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN: //second finger down
            oldDist = spacing(event);
            Log.d(TAG, "oldDist=" + oldDist);
            if (oldDist > 10f) {
                savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                midPoint(mid, event);
                mode = ZOOM;
                Log.d(TAG, "mode=ZOOM" );
            }
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            if (mode == DRAG) {
                //matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                //matrix.postTranslate(event.getX() - start.x, event.getY() - start.y);
                matrix.set(savedMatrix);

                matrix.getValues(matrixValues);
                matrixX = matrixValues[2];
                matrixY = matrixValues[5];
                width = matrixValues[0] * (view.getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth());
                height = matrixValues[4] * (view.getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight());


                dx = event.getX() - start.x;
                dy = event.getY() - start.y;

                //if image will go outside left bound
                if (matrixX + dx  > 0){
                    Log.e("dx","lef bound " + dx);
                    dx = -matrixX;
                }
                //if image will go outside right bound
                if(matrixX + dx + width < view.getWidth()){
                    dx = view.getWidth() - matrixX - width;
                }
                //if image will go oustside top bound
                if (matrixY + dy > 0){
                    dy = -matrixY;
                }
                //if image will go outside bottom bound
                if(matrixY + dy + height < view.getHeight()){
                    dy = view.getHeight() - matrixY - height;
                }

                matrix.postTranslate(dx, dy);
            }
            else if (mode == ZOOM) {
                Float newDist = spacing(event);
                Log.d(TAG, "newDist=" + newDist);
                if (newDist > 10f) {
                    matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                    float scale = newDist / oldDist;
                    float[] values = new float[9];
                    matrix.getValues(values);
                    float currentScale = values[Matrix.MSCALE_X];
                    if(scale * currentScale > MAX_ZOOM)
                        scale = MAX_ZOOM / currentScale;
                    else if (scale * currentScale < MIN_ZOOM)
                        scale = MIN_ZOOM / currentScale;
                    matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);

                }
                break;
            }
    } //perform the transformation.

    view.setImageMatrix(matrix);
    return true; // indicate event was handled

}

private float spacing(MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
    float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
    return (float)Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
}

private void midPoint(PointF point, MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX(0) + event.getX(1);
    float y = event.getY(0) + event.getY(1);
    point.set(x / 2, y / 2);
}

    return drawable;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. We need to create two Rect objects, one is for our view and another for our image according to the view coordinates.

   ```
   float[] values = new float[9];
   matrix.getValues(values);
   float globalX = values[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
   float globalY = values[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];
   float scaleX = values[Matrix.MSCALE_X];
   float scaleY = values[Matrix.MSCALE_Y];
   Rect viewRect = new Rect(0, 0, viewWidth, viewHeight);
   Rect imageRect = new Rect((int) globalX, (int) globalY, Math.round(bitmapWidth * scaleX + globalX),
           Math.round(bitmapHeight * scaleY + globalY));
   ```

   2. If we want our image be always inside our view, then we check this:

      ```
      if (!viewRect.contains(imageRect)) {
          matrix.set(lastSetMatrix); //return to last saved parameters
      }
      ```
   3. Sometimes we need our image always be bigger than our view to position a part of the image inside the view, then we can check this:

      ```
      if (!imageRect.contains(viewRect)) {
         matrix.set(lastSetMatrix);
      }
      ```

Answer (score 0):

I have done this code. when I zoom hen it should not go out of boundry. its working fine.But when it touches cordinate of x=0 and y=0 it do not minimize.

```
int FLAG=0;   



 else if (mode == ZOOM) {

                    float newDistance = spacing(event);

                    Log.i("new distance ", newDistance+"");

                    matrix.getValues(matrixValues);
                    matrixX = matrixValues[2];
                    matrixY = matrixValues[5];
                    width = matrixValues[0]
                            * (((ImageView) view).getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth());
                    height = matrixValues[4]
                            * (((ImageView) view).getDrawable()
                                    .getIntrinsicHeight());

                    dx = event.getX() - start.x;
                    dy = event.getY() - start.y;

                    // if image will go outside left bound
                    if (matrixX + dx < 0) {
                        FLAG=1;
                    }
                    if (matrixX + dx + width > view.getWidth()) {
                        FLAG=1;
                        //dx = view.getWidth() - matrixX - width;
                    }
                    // if image will go oustside top bound
                    if (matrixY + dy < 0) {
                        FLAG=1;
                        //dy = -matrixY;
                    }
                    // if image will go outside bottom bound
                    if (matrixY + dy + height > view.getHeight()) {
                        FLAG=1;
                        //dy = view.getHeight() - matrixY - height;
                    }
                if (matrixX + dx ==0 || matrixY + dy==0){ 
                    FLAG=0;
                }

                    if (newDistance > 10f && FLAG==0) {

                        matrix.set(savedMatrix);

                        float scale = newDistance / oldDistance;

                        float[] values = new float[9];

                        matrix.getValues(values);
                        float currentScale = values[Matrix.MSCALE_X];
                        if (scale * currentScale > MAX_ZOOM)
                            scale = MAX_ZOOM / currentScale;
                        else if (scale * currentScale < MIN_ZOOM)
                            scale = MIN_ZOOM / currentScale;
                        matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);
                    }
                }
                break;
```