# How to avoid zoomed ImageView from being dragged out of the screen?

Tags: android

I have an `ImageView` whose `Drawable` can be zoomed in or out. The `Drawable` can be dragged inside the `ImageView`, but it can be dragged out of the screen so that for example the left border of the `Drawable` may be place at the center of the screen. I tried the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12029204/imageview-drag-limitation-in-android/12029908#12029908) given by Benito Bertoli and it works perfectly for the initial image which is not zoomed. How can I use this solution when the image is zoomed?

Comment: see `Matrix#map*` methods

Comment: @pskink I'm just working on it and trying to make it work somehow.

Comment: yes, i know you are working on it, just see those methods

Comment: @pskink :) I meant you are right, it seems to be a good option and I just found them.

Comment: @mok you managed to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

I do this:

```
if (event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP || event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        float[] matrixValues=new float[9];
        matrix.getValues(matrixValues);
        PointF coordenadas = validatePosition(matrixValues);
        if (coordenadas.x!=0 || coordenadas.y!=0){
            matrix.postTranslate(coordenadas.x,coordenadas.y);
            //view is a imageView
            view.setImageMatrix(matrix);
        }
}
```

and this is the methods:

```
private PointF validatePosition(float[] matrixValues){
    SizeF pantalla=getDisplaySize();
    SizeF zoomed=getImagenZoomSize(matrixValues[Matrix.MSCALE_X],matrixValues[Matrix.MSCALE_Y]);
    //System.out.println("M_TRANS: "+matrixValues[Matrix.M TRANS_X]+","+matrixValues[Matrix.M TRANS_Y]+"  Pantalla:"+pantalla.getWidth()+","+pantalla.getHeight()+"   Imagen:"+zoomed.getWidth()+","+zoomed.getHeight());
    PointF respuesta=new PointF(0,0);
    respuesta.set(calculateAbsolutePosition(matrixValues[Matrix.MTRANS_X],zoomed.getWidth(),pantalla.getWidth()),respuesta.y);
    respuesta.set(respuesta.x,calculateAbsolutePosition(matrixValues[Matrix.MTRANS_Y],zoomed.getHeight(),pantalla.getHeight()));
    return respuesta;
}

private SizeF getDisplaySize(){
    Point dimension=new Point();
    Display display=getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    display.getSize(dimension);
    pantalla=new SizeF(dimension.x,dimension.y);
    return pantalla;
}

private SizeF getImagenZoomSize(float scaleX, float scaleY){
    SizeF original=getOriginalImageSize();
    return new SizeF(original.getWidth()*scaleX,original.getHeight()*scaleY);
}

private float calculateAbsolutePosition(float actual, float medidaImagen, float medidaPantalla){
    float max, min;
    float desplazamiento;
    if (medidaPantalla>medidaImagen){
        max=(medidaPantalla-medidaImagen)/2;
        min=max;
    }
    else{
        max=0;
        min=medidaPantalla-medidaImagen;
    }
    if (actual<min){
        desplazamiento=-actual+min;
    }
    else if (actual>max){
        desplazamiento=-actual+max;
    }
    else{ //no movemos la imagen (desplazamiento=0)
        desplazamiento=0;
    }
    return desplazamiento;
}
```